# After adding new class file to App_Code, build action is Content instead of Compile

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2008-sp1

In VS2008, I am adding new classes to a web project.

When I right-click on App-Code -> Add -> New Item -> Class ...

The build action for the newly created item is set to content instead of compile. This seems like it would be a problem with the template. I've found several others through google who have run into this issue, but nobody seemed to have found a more permanent solution, other than "change it from content to compile after creation."

My question: Does anyone know of a fix for this, official or otherwise?

Comment: is that a folder based web site, or a project file based one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App_Code is a special folder meant for folder based projects.

This is just a hunch, but it might be that you have a project file based project, instead of a simple folder based one.

Comment: Yep, turns out Web Applications don't belong having App_Code folders at all. I confirmed that simply adding the class file to the root of the project set the correct action. One of our developers added the App_Code folder because he's used to working with Web Site Projects. Solution was to get rid of App_Code.